# Using an image usemap with custom HTML element?

Tags: javascript, html, css

In the code example below, I'm trying to define my own custom element, `<custelem>`, and I can style it fine; however, I'd also like to assign an image map to it - but my attempt below fails, as there are never mouseovers on the hotspots in Firefox:

```
<html>
<head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
  <title>Test</title>
  <script type="text/javascript">
  </script>
  <style type="text/css">
#myone {
  border-color: blue; border-width: 3px; border-style: solid;
  display: block;
  background-color: #AAA;
  /* convert -size 300x300 xc:red red.png */
  background: #EFEFEF url(red.png) 50% 50% no-repeat padding-box border-box scroll;
  background-size: contain;
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
}
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <custelem id="myone" usemap="#TEST"></custelem> <!-- renders the css, but hotspot mouseovers do not work -->
  <!-- <img src="red.png" id="myone" usemap="#TEST"></img> <!-- works in FF, but has to have src attribute for mouseovers -->
  <map id="TEST" name="TEST">
    <area href="javascript:alert('A1')" id="A1" alt="A1 text" shape="rect" coords="50,50,100,100"/>
    <area href="javascript:alert('A2')" id="A2" alt="A2 text" shape="rect" coords="150,150,200,200"/>
  </map>
</body>

</html>
```

Can I somehow use a usemap with a custom element - either via css, or JS?

Comment: Any reason you want to use a custom element? If you give your img element a src of a 1px transparent gif you can then style the `img` element with a css background the same as if it were your custom element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not an usemap, it's an image-map. This explains why it only works on images. 
But you can fix this with JS:

```
[].forEach.call(document.querySelectorAll("custelem[usemap]"), function(node){
    var img = new Image();
  img.className = "image-map";
  img.useMap = node.getAttribute("usemap");
  img.title = node.getAttribute("title") || "";
  img.src = "data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAEAAAABCAYAAAAfFcSJAAAADUlEQVQImWNgYGBgAAAABQABh6FO1AAAAABJRU5ErkJggg=="; // 1x1 transparent png
  node.removeAttribute("usemap");
  node.appendChild(img);
});
```

and a little bit css:

```
custelem {
  position: relative;
}
custelem img.image-map{
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/u8n6fygz/

Comment: wow @Thomas, many thanks for this - exactly the kind of solution I was looking for! PS: for those wondering how to modify the OP with this soluion, just make sure the JS is inside `window.onload = function(e){ ... }`  Cheers!

Comment: Since this code removes the `usemap`-attribute from the `custelem` you can call this code over and over again without side-effects. Just in case you intend to modify your document, and create new/more `custelem`s.